# Sharing Mac's wifi connection with iPhone, for iOS app development?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, internet-sharing

How can I share my Mac's wi-fi connection with my iPhone?

I am currently travelling (roaming out of country) and I am needing to work on the development of my iOS app, though an internet connection appears to be needed for the phone, otherwise it won't approve the signature of the "in development" app, even though I had previously deployed it to the phone. I am now in a location where my computer managed to connect to wi-fi, but not my iPhone (sign-in process is spotty), so I am trying to see what possibilities there are to be able to deploy my app.

BTW certain functionality can be tested in the simulator, but there is other functionality that needs a real device.

What I have tried:

- Connecting phone via USB and in "Sharing -> Internet Sharing" specify "iPhone USB", then enabling it
- Connecting phone via Bluetooth and then in "Sharing -> Internet Sharing" specify "Bluetooth PAN", then enabling it

Is there another solution or a step I might have overlooked?

I am using iOS 9.3.1 and MacOS X 10.11.4.

Comment: Did you try connecting to the iPhone via USB and selecting Personal Hotspot on the iPhone?  That's what I do to access my cell network on my Mac.

Comment: I am not wanting to use my cell phone network. I am roaming internationally and the cost per MB is prohibitive.

Comment: Will you be able to connect your Mac to the internet via ethernet?  That's the only way I know to create a hotspot from your Mac to your iPhone.

Comment: I am roaming with access to wifi only, hence the challenge.